# How to use clang compiler in Dymola 2021 - Windows

Tags: dymola

I installed MS Build Tools 2019 (along with clang) and verified the compiler (Visual Studio 2019) but couldn't figure out how to set the compiler to use clang in Dymola. The documentation only mentions support for clang in the linux version but doesn't seem to mention anything about Windows support.

I was wondering if anyone has figured out how to set the compiler to clang through MS Build.